# SQL: Group By...Having Issue

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm trying to wrap my head around this SQL query but am really having some trouble.

I have a table with `id` and `address` (where `id` is just a lowercase `addresss` and `"id-"` prefix. I want to get all of the elements on this list where the id and address DON'T match, **but the address is** **shared by 2 elements in the list.**

For example:

A: `id="id-abcde"`, `address=aBcDe`

B: `id="id-zxwy"`, `address=aBcDe`

I would like to return B which shares an address in the table and whose address is different from its id.

My query as it stands now is

```
select a.id, a.address 
from users as a 
where a.id != concat('id-', lower(a.address)) 
group by a.address, a.id 
having count(1) > 1
```

But, this is not returning the correct results.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: why do you have a group by without an aggregate function (like count, sum, min, max)? You don't need it together with having.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select u.id, u.address 
from (select u.*, count(*) over (partition by address) as cnt
      from users u
     ) u
where u.id <> concat('id-', lower(u.address)) and cnt = 2;
```

If you want *at least two elements*, then use `cnt > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need group by or having for this

try

```
select a.id, a.address from users a
where a.id != concat('id-',lower(a.address))
```

if you have multiple similar entries add `distinct` in the first line

```
select distinct a.id, a.address from users a
```

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ . . . I don't think a downvote is warranted, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: yup; you are correct. I missed this line:  "but the address is shared by 2 elements in the list."

Answer (score 0):

Try * insetead of 1, that way you're testing for rows with more than one occurrence and not just one column.

```
select a.id, a.address from users as a where 
a.id != concat('id-', lower(a.address)) 
group by a.address, a.id 
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between `count(*)` and `count(1)`